# Troubles installing Heroku Toolbelt ("panic" message)

Tags: windows, heroku, toolbelt

I have installed Heroku Toolbelt for Windows. It was working very well until now. But when I type "Heroku login", I now get either this message:

[panic:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyxoY.png)

Or I get this message:

panic: mkdir G:: The system cannot find the path specified.

```
goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x7390a0, 0x110a4140)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:481 +0x326
main.must(0x32a80000, 0x110a4140)
        /home/ubuntu/.go_workspace/src/github.com/heroku/cli/io.go:188 +0x44
main.configHome(0x0, 0x0)
            /home/ubuntu/.go_workspace/src/github.com/heroku/cli/filesystem.go:66 +0x17d
main.init()
            /home/ubuntu/.go_workspace/src/github.com/heroku/cli/filesystem.go:27 +0x346
panic:
```

Do your have any idea why and what can I do ?

Thanks a lot! I am stuck with this issue since one week
Best
Julien

Comment: Is that issue arised after it auto updated toolbelt? If so, try uninstalling the toolbelt, along with the local folder and then reinstall it. Try [this](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/1949)

Comment: Ok. I just noticed that the problem does not arise when I connect from home, so I guess it is related to my company's network?